# Is every (sufficiently nice) function a solution to an autonomous ode?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

For whatever reason, I'm suddenly interested in whether or not one can characterized those functions which are solutions to autonomous ode. The first natural question to ask, then, is: are all $C^1([a,b])$ functions solutions to some autonomous ode?

If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counter example, sine function can not because its derivative $\cos(x)$ can not be written as $f(\sin(x))$ for any function $f$.

Since
$\cos(\pi/4) = \sin(\pi/4) = \sqrt{2}/2,$
we must have $f(\sqrt{2}/2) = \sqrt{2}/2$.

$\sin(3\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}/2$ but $\cos(3\pi/4) = -\sqrt{2}/2$.

Edit: I guess for invertible $C^1$ function, this would work. For $u'(x) = f(u(x))$, we can define $f(x) = u'(u^{-1}(x))$.